# selenium via python to click on the next hyperlink

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape this website: https://travel.padi.com/s/liveaboards/caribbean/?page=2
Here is the screenshot of what I am seeing:
[image]

but I am stuck on the 'Next 4 trips' button. I got the code before to go through the page, lift out each boat (card), and lift out the date and trip cost. But this script only works on the current page, not the subsequent months. Those months can be accessed by clicking the 'Next 4 trips' button. But I don't know how to formulate the xpath to get there and click it.

```
import selenium.webdriver
import time
import pprint
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


def trip_cost_filter_for_savings(trip_costs_list):
    for i in trip_costs_list:

        if 'Sold out' in i.text or 'Charter only' in i.text:
            return 0

        elif '/ trip' not in i.text:
            #this is a price reduced item

            return int(trip_costs_list[3].text.strip('CAD ').replace(',', ''))
        else:
            return int(trip_costs_list[1].text.strip('CAD ').replace(',', ''))






def find_my_stuff(boat_price_dict, driver, xpath_item_cards):
    all_cards = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath_item_cards)

    for card in all_cards:
################################
#here is where i plan to click the 'Next 4 Trips' button, and put the stuff below in a while #loop, so while i can still find a 'Next 4 Trips' button, keep clicking and scraping. 
        next_month = card.find_element_by_xpath('.//[@class="next-month"]/span')
        print(next_month)
################################
        title = card.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@class="shop-title"]/span')
        desc = card.find_element_by_xpath('.//p[@class="shop-desc-text"]')

        all_dates = card.find_elements_by_css_selector('.cell.date')
        all_prices = card.find_elements_by_css_selector('.cell.pricing')

        dates_trips_price_list=[]
        for date, price in zip(all_dates, all_prices):
            day, month = date.find_elements_by_tag_name('span')
            trip_date = day.text+' '+month.text

            trip_costs_list = price.find_elements_by_tag_name('span')

            trip_cost=trip_cost_filter_for_savings(trip_costs_list)

            dates_trips_price_list.append([trip_date, trip_cost])

        boat_price_dict[title.text]=dates_trips_price_list



def write_to_sql(boat_price_dict):
    pass



def main():
    xpath_item_cards = '//div[@class="boat search-page-item-card "]'
    xpath_pagination = '//div[@class="pagination-wrap"]'
    boat_price_dict = {}
    carribean_page_url = 'https://travel.padi.com/s/liveaboards/caribbean/'
    SE_asia_page_url = 'https://travel.padi.com/s/liveaboards/caribbean/'

    only_1_page = False

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

    driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

    driver.get(carribean_page_url)
    #driver.get(SE_asia_page_url)


    time.sleep(15)  # TODO: change this to wait for webpage to finish loading instead of hard coding it.
    print('finished waiting 15 secs')

    try:
        tmp = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_pagination)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        only_1_page=True
        pass

    find_my_stuff(boat_price_dict, driver, xpath_item_cards)

    if not only_1_page:
        pages=tmp.text[1:]
        #print(pages)
        for i in pages:

            driver.get(carribean_page_url+'?page='+i)
            #print(carribean_page_url+'?page='+i)
            time.sleep(15)
            find_my_stuff(boat_price_dict, driver, xpath_item_cards)

    pprint.pprint(boat_price_dict)



    driver.quit()

    write_to_sql(boat_price_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Comment: Did you try '//div[@class="next"]' as your xpath? It should output all the divs containing text "Next 4 trips".Then you can click on each of them until you get to the end. I can provide complete solution if it works for you.

Comment: it did output all the divs, but when i try .click() i get an exception that says item not clickable.

Comment: i was able to use .click on the chrome dev console, but that's in java script.

Comment: Instead of clicking on the hyperlink, sometimes getting the `href` attribute from the element and navigating to the page works better.

Comment: but its not a hyper link, if i inspect the element it is not a button nor does it have a href, updated question with screenshot.